# How to remove a mouse wheel listener in SWT

Tags: java, swt, scrolledcomposite

I am trying to remove and replace a mouse wheel listener on a ScrolledComposite in SWT. The scrolled composite has a removeMouseWheelListener method, however it has no way of gaining access to a the mouse wheel listener to remove it. I have tried the getListeners() method:

```
MouseWheelListener mouseWheelListener = (MouseWheelListener) scrollable.getListeners(SWT.MouseWheel)[0];
```

but this produces an a casting error so getListeners must not retrieve the same type of listeners. I have tried creating a new listener and removing it from the ScrolledComposite:

```
MouseWheelListener scroller = new MouseWheelListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseScrolled(MouseEvent e) {
        Point currentScroll = scrollable.getOrigin();
        scrollable.setOrigin(currentScroll.x, currentScroll.y - (e.count * 5));
    }
};
scrollable.removeMouseWheelListener(scroller);
```

This does not remove the listener though. Of course, if I had access to the original MouseWheelListener that was added this would not be a problem, but I don't. 
Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to add and remove a listener? I don't understand. If you want a specific mouse wheel listener just add a new one by using addMouseWheelListener() method. But if you don't want your mouse wheel listener to do nothing just don't do anything in public void mouseScrolled( MouseEvent e )

Comment: There is a MouseWheelListener that gets added to my ScrolledComposite. What I want to be able to do is remove that one, and put a new one in. If it is impossible to do this, why is there a removeMouseWheelListener() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getListeners` will return a listener of type `TypedListener` for a mouse wheel listener.

`TypedListener.getEventListener()` will return the `MouseWheelListener`.